# how to define negative range for NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, .net, forms

for example I wanted NumericUpDown range to between (-100, 100) but since ) NumericUpDown  is an decimal quantity(0, ......).so how to make NumericUpDownto take negative range.

Comment: You should be able to set `Minimum` and `Maximum` property of NumericUpDown control... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Here you can copy paste and run

```
numericUpDown1 = new NumericUpDown();
// Set the Minimum, Maximum, and initial Value.
numericUpDown1.Value = 0;
numericUpDown1.Maximum = 100;
numericUpDown1.Minimum = -100;

//You can set each click to increment number for next number, even in decimals (The default value is 1)
numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 2;
numericUpDown1.Increment = 0.25M;
```

note : @Chetan Ranpariya has given us right link for further read.

[Link to read - Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.increment?view=net-5.0)